# Understanding conditions for height being fixed

Tags: css

Consider:

```
.centered {
    position       : absolute;
    top            : 0;
    left           : 0;
    right          : 0;
    bottom         : 0;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    align-items    : center;
}

.problem {
  width: fit-content;
}

.scrollable {
  width: fit-content;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```
<div class="centered">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Line1</h1>
      <h1>Line2</h1>
      <h1>Line3</h1>
      <h1>Line4</h1>
      <h1>Line5</h1>
      <h1>Line6</h1>
      <h1>Line7</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `scrollable` div gets a fixed height:

[image]

Why is the height fixed?

Next, let us add another div (`problem`):

```
<div class="centered">
  <div class="problem">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Line1</h1>
      <h1>Line2</h1>
      <h1>Line3</h1>
      <h1>Line4</h1>
      <h1>Line5</h1>
      <h1>Line6</h1>
      <h1>Line7</h1>
    </div>
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the height of `scrollable` is not fixed:

[image]

How did the addition of `problem` change the height of `scrollable`?

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mgoldenb/pen/zYEYLxx?editors=1100) to play with.

**Clarification.** The actual solution is to move `overflow-y: auto; margin: auto;` up into `.problem`. However, the question is not to solve the problem, but to explain why the height is fixed in the first case (and how that height is calculated), but not fixed in the second case.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Adding a new div will logically make your code different so you have a different behavior.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The question is to explain why the height is fixed in the first case (and how that height is calculated), but not fixed in the second case.

Comment: because it's a flex item limited to its parent height and you added overflow:scroll

Comment: @TemaniAfif Simple and to the point. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You do not need problem tag and class,so Remove them and just modify scrollable class to:

```
.scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I know! The question asked for an explanation, not a solution. Also, you cannot know what  role that extra div plays in the actual context. The examples in good SO questions are purposely minimal, so as to emphasize the issue in question.